# Any news about the removal of the unwanted Scopes on Touch?

Tags: ubuntu-touch

Been Using Touch for a few weeks now and generally happy with it, but as I never use the scopes I want to remove 90% of them. There seems to be a large amount of rubbish files attached to these and its all clogging up my phones tiny amount of free space.

I know there are ways to remove them manually, but does anyone know if this issue will be fixed soon in the updates?

Cheers.

Comment: This question is off topic here, we are not the developers and do not know eta of features for Ubuntu. All anyone can offer is opinion and that is no use at all.

Comment: Sorry if its off topic. Was just hoping somebody might know if it was part of one of the future OTA's, all the developer stuff is beyond my understanding :)

Comment: It is beyond us too, we are just an end user community, so we simply don't know. People could speculate but that does not really get you what you asked for. You can ask the devs directly here https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-phone

Comment: Thanks Mark, ill take a look and post my question there.

Comment: This question is ontopic here, the developers do read the questions on here and answer them.

Answer (score 4):

You can remove some scopes and apps using `sudo click unregister --user=phablet PACKAGE-NAME`.

However, if they are installed inside the read-only part of the phone, then they will only be hidden, and not removed. Currently there's no way around that.

Comment: Thanks. Its annoying none of this can be done via the file manager!!!

Comment: The file manager is a file manager, not a package manager :)

Comment: That's a good point :)

Answer (score 0):

Go to **Ubuntu store** (from Apps scope) and search by the name of the scope you want to remove. Then open the relevant result, you should find one **Uninstall** option.

Comment: Cheers, I have done, but there are still loads that do not appear in the Store. I did remember reading somewhere you can remove these using the terminal, but i really don't want to muck it up!