# How to completely uninstall a click package?

Tags: package-management, ubuntu-touch, 15.04, scopes, click-packages

I'm trying to uninstall the BBC news scope (among others) on my Nexus 4 running Ubuntu Touch, but failing to do so completely. The package name for the BBC scope is `com.canonical.scopes.bbc`, so I've gone ahead and run

```
sudo click unregister com.canonical.scopes.bbc
```

this removes the package from `click list`, however this still leaves the package installed on the system.

For instance, even though the scope is no longer shown in the "Manage" view, the package is still listed in the "Permy" app even after a reboot.

Trying to run the unregister command again yields:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/click", line 110, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/usr/bin/click", line 106, in main
    return mod.run(args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/click/commands/unregister.py", line 55, in run
    old_version = registry.get_version(package)
GLib.Error: click_user_error-quark: com.canonical.scopes.bbc is hidden for user phablet (6)
```

How do I completely remove the package from my phone? Some other scopes don't even appear to be listed by `click list`... so I'm facing similar difficulty removing those.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Please don't add "bonus" questions. Ask a separate question instead.

Comment: @muru, perhaps my phrasing was poor, but I do believe it was pertinent to the original question.

Comment: looks like you can't. See popey's answer for this question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/795959/any-news-about-the-removal-of-the-unwanted-scopes-on-touch/795968

Comment: @pomsky thanks for the link, but that just doesn't seem right; the packages are installed *somewhere*, so there has to be a way to remove them somehow... right?

Comment: did you try this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/347879/how-do-i-un-install-remove-a-click-package/354203#354203

Comment: @konrad there isn't a way in the UI to remove scopes, as would be suggested for regular applications. Also, I want to completely remove the package from the system... click unregister doesn't totally remove it -- it just hides it from the user.